# Are Constructors Synchronized Until Totally Complete?

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor, synchronized

I'm building a program that requires the construction of some objects that require such intense computation to create, my smartest course would be to have them built in their own dedicated threads, while the master thread keeps grinding away on other things until the objects are needed.

So I thought about creating a special class specifically designed to create custom objects in their own thread. Like so:

```
public abstract class DedicatedThreadBuilder<T> {

    private T object;

    public DedicatedThreadBuilder() {
        DedicatedThread dt = new DedicatedThread(this);
        dt.start();
    }

    private void setObject(T i) {
        object = i;
    }

    protected abstract T constructObject();

    public synchronized T getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    private class DedicatedThread extends Thread {

        private DedicatedThreadBuilder dtb;

        public DedicatedThread(DedicatedThreadBuilder builder){
            dtb = builder;
        }

        public void run() {
            synchronized(dtb) {
                dtb.setObject(dtb.constructObject());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

My only concern is that this mechanism will only work properly if the master thread (i.e. the thread that constructs the *DedicatedThreadBuilder*) has a synchronized lock on the *DedicatedThreadBuilder* until it's construction is completed, and therefore blocks the *DedicatedThread*'s attempt to build the product object until it has finished construction of the *DedicatedThreadBuilder*. Why? Because the subclasses of *DedicatedThreadBuilder* will no doubt need to be constructed with parameters the will need to be passed into their own private storage, so that they can be used in the *constructObject()* process.

e.g.

```
public class JellybeanStatisticBuilder extends DedicatedThreadBuilder<JellybeanStatistics> {

    private int greens;
    private int blacks;
    private int yellows;

    public JellybeanStatisticBuilder(int g, int b, int y) {
        super();
        greens = g;
        blacks = b;
        yellows = y;
    }

    protected JellybeanStatistics constructObject() {
        return new JellybeanStatistics(greens, blacks, yellows);
    }

}
```

This will only work properly if the object is blocked to other threads until after it is **completely** constructed. Otherwise, the *DedicatedThread* might try to build the object before the necessary variables have been assigned.

So is that how Java works?

Comment: Don't do it.  What evidence do you have that you have a problem?

Comment: @duffymo I don't know that I will have a problem. Hence my question. I want to know whether or not this class will work properly before I try to build it.

Comment: I assume (please correct if I'm wrong) that @duffymo means a problem at all, in the first place, before ever even introducing this entire factory thread. If you know for certain that the creation is super heavy and takes lots of time and definitely will cause a problem, then carry on. Otherwise, you might want to perform some tests to see if you even need this.

Comment: Yes, it'll work correctly.  Writing mutli-threaded code is hard even for smart, experienced developers.  Don't take on such a thing unless you know it's necessary.  Write it simply and clearly, profile it, and address issues that you have data for.

Comment: Oh! I understand now! Well, without going in to too much detail, I know for certain that the objects will be very heavyweight to construct as there will (potentially) be many megabytes of data that need to be processed, through complex calculations and in some cases, processed numerous times.

Comment: Thanks @duffymo!

Comment: I don't know anything about your objects or your use case, but I'd wonder if you could take advantage of a factory object and eager evaluation.  If you can create and cache objects on start up it'll mean a slower start up but faster performance once the app is up and running.  If it has to be lazy loading, and you don't want users to have to block the main thread while the objects are being created, perhaps a asynch creation with callback is the way to go.

Comment: My original comment still stands: write it simply and clearly using ctors at first.  Don't assume a problem.  Get data.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to have some sort of synchronised factory class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class SyncFactory<T> {    
    // alternatively, use newCachedThreadPool or newFixedThreadPool if you want to allow some degree of parallel construction
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public Future<T> create() {        
        return executor.submit(() -> {
            return new T();
        });
    }
}
```

Now you'd replace usages of `T` that may need to happen before `T` is ready with `Future<T>`, and have a choice between calling its `Future.get()` method to block until it's ready, set a timeout, or to call `Future.isDone()` to check up on the construction without blocking. In addition, instead of polling the Future, you may want to have  the factory call a callback or post an event to notify the main thread when it has completed construction.

Comment: I'm leaving my answer since I think it still provides useful information about OP's code, but _this answer provides a much better alternative_. @Cambot I recommend you give what I said a little bit of thought, but then to go this route instead.

Answer (score 0):

*If* (**big** if) this is truly needed (think that one over first)...

The overall idea you are heading toward can work, but your code is confusing and, at first glance by me anyway, appears that it might not work. This type of complexity which can break things is a very good reason to double-think and even triple-think heading down this path.

The major problem I spotted right away is that you are only ever creating 1 instance of the object. If this is a factory which just creates things on another thread, then the `DedicatedThread` should be called upon in `DedicatedThreadBuilder`'s `constructObject`, not in its constructor.

If, on the other hand, you actually intend for the `DedicatedThreadBuilder` to only create 1 instance of `T`, then this abstraction seems unnecessary... just move `DedicatedThread`'s behavior out to `DedicatedThreadBuilder`, as `DedicatedThreadBuilder` doesn't really seem to be doing anything extra.

Second, a minor thing that isn't *incorrect* so much as it is just unnecessary: you have an inner class which you pass an instance of the outer class to its constructor (that is, `DedicatedThread`'s constructor takes a reference to its parent `DedicatedThreadBuilder`). This is unnecessary, as non-static inner classes are already linked to their outer classes, so the inner class can reference the outer class without any extra reference to it.

Third, if you move the behavior out of the constructor and into a separate method, then you could synchronize that. Personally, I would have had the `constructObject` be the thing that kicked off the process, so that calling `dtb.constructObject()` started the object's creation, and `constructObject` itself set `object = newlyCreatedThing` when it was done. Then you could synchronize that method if you want, or do whatever, and not have to worry about the constructor possibly not behaving how you want - in my opinion you should not generally have to worry that a constructor might have some odd side effects.

Fourth, do you have any way to know when the object is ready and available for getting? You might want to add some mechanism for that, such as an observer or other callback.

Comment: Well, to answer your fourth point, wouldn't the fact that the getObject() is synchronized block all other attempts to access the object until the constructor thread has finished building it? And as for the rest... not sure I understood it, TBH. Your suggesting that I move execution of the thread outside of the constructor, to insure the construction is complete before the thread is executed?

Comment: @Cambot In general, sort of. But if that is the only thing you rely on, is it really any better than leaving it single-threaded? Do you merely want to set up the object for creation, do a known, specific set of things, then come back and wait for the creation to finish? That seems to be the only case where this would be useful to rely on synchronization in that manner. However, you could encounter problems with thread interruption relying on that. If I recall (been a while, so double-check it), interrupt can disrupt a wait on a synchronization, meaning you can't rely on it.

Comment: @Cambot For the second part of your comment: I suggested a few things, one of which was to reduce the complexity by moving the `DedicatedThread` behavior out into the `DedicatedThreadBuilder`, as the separation doesn't seem to net you anything, and also moving the `dt.start()` to the `constructObject` yes... assuming you want to be able to use this like a factory and create multiple things.

Comment: Well, no. My intention was to use each subclass to simply create one single, very-time-consuming-to-create object, and then to retain that object for other processes to access at their convienience. Once it had finished building it's one and only output, the constructor side of this class would never be activated again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the subclass before it is constructed.  It doesn't really have anything to do with multithreading.   If you were calling `constructObject` directly from the `DedicatedThreadBuilder` constructor, it would be just as bad.

The reasonable implementation that is closet to what you have is just to provide `DedicatedThreadBuidler` with a separate `start()` method that should be called after the object is constructed.

Or you could have it extend `Thread` and use the Thread methods.

Or you could have it implement `Runnable` so you could use it with a `Thread` or an `Executor` or whatever.

Comment: So, in other words, there's no way to convieniently frame the entire process into the constructor? I'm bound to having it need to be a 2 line process at the very least? I suppose that's not really anything to grip about, although I would've loved to be able to create a one-stop abstract class that takes care of the whole process. I guess constructors don't synchronize their objects afterall. :(